# Symfony2 - TagWeights not being set and weighted in array

Tags: symfony, tags, tag-cloud

I have a method setup to weigh the tags that are being used the most. I am using the example  from here as a learning exercise: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/customising-the-view-more-with-twig.html (see Tag Cloud) I am doing this slightly different as I am using Tags as an entity and not a string property of Blog Entity based on the link.

Tag is setup as a ManyToMany/ManyToMany to Blog entity, see below.

**The problem I am having is tags are being retrieved as intended but however it's not set apparently therefore all tags are returning as an integer of 1. How can I correct this? Am I calling the tags incorrectly to where it's not taking account for which ones are being used more than once?**

`$tagWeights[$tag['tag']] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;`

**getTagWeights (var dumping $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] returns an int of 1)**

```
public function getTags()
{
    $tags = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.tag')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $tags;
}

public function getTagWeights($tags)
{
    $tagWeights = array();

    if (empty($tags))
        return $tagWeights;

    foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {
        $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;
        var_dump($tagWeights[$tag['tag']]);
    }

    // Shuffle the tags
    uksort($tagWeights, function() {
        return rand() > rand();
    });

    $max = max($tagWeights);

    // Max of 5 weights
    $multiplier = ($max > 5) ? 5 / $max : 1;

    foreach ($tagWeights as &$tag)
    {
        $tag = ceil($tag * $multiplier);
    }

    return $tagWeights;
}
```

**Tag entity**

```
class Tag
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tag", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $tag;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="tags")
 */
protected $blogs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->blogs = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set tag
 *
 * @param string $tag
 * @return Tag
 */
public function setTag($tag)
{
    $this->tag = $tag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tag
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTag()
{
    return $this->tag;
}

/**
 * Add blogs
 *
 * @param \AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog $blogs
 * @return Tag
 */
public function addBlog(\AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog $blogs)
{
    $this->blogs[] = $blogs;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove blogs
 *
 * @param \AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog $blogs
 */
public function removeBlog(\AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog $blogs)
{
    $this->blogs->removeElement($blogs);
}

/**
 * Get blogs
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getBlogs()
{
    return $this->blogs;
}
}
```

**Blog entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="blogs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $tags;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add tags
 *
 * @param \AcmeBundle\Entity\Tag $tags
 * @return Blog
 */
public function addTag(\AcmeBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tags;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove tags
 *
 * @param \AcmeBundle\Entity\Tag $tags
 */
public function removeTag(\AcmeBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tags);
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your function is returning 1 always is because you do the following

```
foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag['tag']])) ? $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] + 1 : 1;
    var_dump($tagWeights[$tag['tag']]);
}
```

And you iterate once for each tag, therefore $tagWeights[$tag['tag']] is not acceded more than once per tag, hence always has the value 1.

One way to do this, and thus you wouldn't have to change much code, would be use the blogs instead the tags as below:

```
foreach ($blogs as $blog)
{
    foreach($blog->getTags() as $tag){
        $tagWeights[$tag->getTag()] = (isset($tagWeights[$tag->getTag()])) ? $tagWeights[$tag->getTag()] + 1 : 1;
        var_dump($tagWeights[$tag->getTag()]);
    }
}
```

And you'd need to pass the $blogs variable to the function instead $tags

```
public function getTagWeights($blogs)
{
    ...
}
```

The code above is not tested, but it would be something similar.

I think that another problem is that in your Tag entity, you doesn't use the unique annotation for tag, and in this way, it's possible that there are some tags with exactly the same name, and it's not the expected behavior for the tags cloud. You should do something like this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tag", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $tag;
```

Comment: Ok I've added the unique=true and it still doesn't add weights to it. How do I resolve the first problem?

Comment: @dizzyd I've edited my answer explaining a possible solution.

Comment: Ok, I've tried this and no tags are found. Do I need to change my getTags() method to get from the blog entity instead?

Comment: I'd do a getBlogs() function to achieve that and then use the above code.

Comment: When I use the `foreach ($blog->getTags() as $tag)` I get the following error: `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getTags() on a non-object in /var/www/html/Symfony/src/AcmeBundle/Entity/TagRepository.php line 53`

Comment: You could use \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($blogs); before the first 'foreach' in order to see what is the variable $blogs value.

Comment: I will check this. I understand that in the original use of getTagWeights() it's checking to see how many tags are being set then adding a +1 to it, as tags is part of the blog entity. Does that line of code that adds a +1 need to be changed or will this work as you have suggested by using `($blog->getTags() as $tag)`

Comment: I've done a var_dump; die(); on $blogs before the first foreach and it lists all the blog objects. However when I use it based on your code above, I get the follow: `ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined property: AcmeBundle\Entity\Blog::$getTags in /var/www/html/Symfony/src/AcmeBundle/Entity/TagRepository.php line 52` when getTags is setup in the Blog Entity.

Comment: Fixed that error mentioned above. Forgot to use the () in $blog->getTags in the foreach. Now I get the following: `FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot use object of type AcmeBundle\Entity\Tag as array in /var/www/html/Symfony/src/AcmeBundle/Entity/TagRepository.php line 54` when using $blog->getTags() in the first foreach loop.

Comment: Your $blog->getTags shouldn't return a Tag entity, should return an ArrayCollection of Tag entities. You could dump the $blogs and see what is in the $tags attribute and after that, you could dump $blog->getTags() to see what is returning this function. Could you paste the line 54 of your TagRepository.php?

Comment: I just re-looked over the code, I think the problem was I didn't change $tag['tag']] to $tag->getTag(). I just re-did your suggestion and it works!!! You are a genius. One final thing, can you edit your answer and explain how it works step by step with you solution? I'm trying to learn and understand more. If you don't mind.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful it you can explain why you used $blogs and why that worked, instead of using $tags?